# Facebook API / SDK Keep User Logged In

Tags: facebook, api

So, I've been building a web app that shares images to Instagram and Facebook.

While signing up with email and password, the user also stores their Instagram username and password.

The result is, whenever they decide to share to Insta, the app logs in for them and shares the image.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same with Facebook? Can I use a stored username+password to log in for the user when they decide to share?

Comment: do you really store username and password for instagram users? that is definitely a no-go. use the api, if something is not possible with the api: don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a stored username+password to log in for the user when they decide to share [on Facebook]?

No, you can not - and you are not even allowed to, Facebook explicitly forbids apps from doing that.

If you want the user to login to Facebook - then you need to implement the OAuth login flow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

---

But you can not share/ post to Facebook in the name of a user via API any more anyways, since `publish_actions` permission has been removed. You can only let them share links by using the Share or Feed dialog. So for each image that you want to share, you will need a unique URL that returns the right OG meta data to specify that image as the thumbnail.